# Getting input text value with jQuery send the input name instead of the actual value

Tags: jquery, forms

I need some advice,

I have a simple html input type text field:

```
<p><input id="mrmid" type="text" name="mrmid" size="30" /></p>
```

I am trying to get his values using a submit function, like this:

```
$("#myform").submit(function(){
    var mrmid = $("#mrmid").val();
    alert("mrmid");
});
```

Instead of the submitted value, lets say I submit "123", the alert alertss "mrmid" (the input name).

Why is this happening?

Is this the way to go, or should I use the serializeArray() method? Which I know it works and I saw it documented on stack.

Ty

Comment: It's not printing the input name, it's printing your string:  "mrmid" is a string literal.  You want the variable: mrmid (no quotes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to use `alert(mrmid);` instead of `alert("mrmid");`

Answer (score 0):

You are alerting string **"mrmid"** instead of variable **mrmid**.

Change

```
alert("mrmid");
```

to

```
alert(mrmid);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are alerting a string "mrmid", not the value in `mrmid` variable.
Remove double quotes for `mrmid` in `alert`

```
$("#eloqua").submit(function(){
    var mrmid = $("#mrmid").val();
    alert(mrmid);
});
```